# Adding multiple events to the same HTML Image() object

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I'm trying to add events to an Image object, which I create dynamically (using the Image() constructor) and bind to a HTML canvas element. I have successfully added the "load" event. However, I can't add any other events, such as "click" or "mousedown". The Javascript and HTML code blocks are pasted below.

The "load" event handler is called and I get the alert. However, the "mousedown" event is not. Why do I see this behaviour and how can I correct it?

Many thanks for your help.

ps: The "mouseup" event on  element works fine.

```js
function myDraw(){
    var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
    
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        alert('Loaded! img type is \n' + typeof img);
        // execute drawImage statements here
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        canvas.setAttribute('width', 1000);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', 1000);

        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.drawImage(img, 200,200);
    }, false);

    img.src = './floorplan.jpg'; // Set source path

    img.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
        alert('Mouse down');
    }, false);

    const c1 = document.getElementById('h1');

    c1.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
        alert('Mouse up');
    }, false);
}

myDraw();
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 id="h1">CANVAS</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <!--img id="fplan" src = "./floorplan.jpg" /-->
</div>

<script src='./script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I needed to add the event listener to the canvas element and not the image loaded on to the canvas.

The `c1.addEventListener('click',clickZoom, false);` line achieves this.

```js
const c1 = document.getElementById('canvas');
c1.setAttribute('width', 1000);
c1.setAttribute('height', 1000);

const ctx = c1.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element

function myDraw(){
    img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // execute drawImage statements here
        ctx.drawImage(img, 200,200);
    }, false);

    img.src = './floorplan.jpg'; // Set source path

    c1.addEventListener('click',clickZoom, false);
}

function clickZoom() {
    alert('Zoom clicked');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 200, 200, ctx.canvas.width * 0.5, ctx.canvas.height * 0.5);  // this needs changing wrt image size not canvas size!!
}

myDraw();
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 id="h1">CANVAS</h1>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <!--img id="fplan" src = "./floorplan.jpg" /-->
</div>

<script src='./script.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @JoseLora, I have further explained my solution. Hope this helps!